# Coldfusion sql error only occurring on one instance of app

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml

I am running two instances of the same app, however only on one I get an error when trying to display unlabeled images.

The log says:

> Error Executing Database Query.You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 3 The specific sequence of files
>   included or processed is:
>   [obscured]...images_archive.cfm,
>   line: 24

Line 24 of this file is:

```
WHERE <cfloop query="unlabeledTags">tagID <> #ID#<cfif #currentRow# NEQ #recordCount#> AND </cfif></cfloop>
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Keep in mind line numbers are approximate. But if the `unlabeledTags` query was empty you would end up with `WHERE (nothing after it)`, which would definitely cause a syntax error. But that is just a guess. It is impossible to say without seeing the generated sql and values of the variables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Leigh said your issue is probably with an empty query set, but to clean up your code a bit I'd recommend writing your SQL like this.

```
WHERE tagID NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ValueList(unlabeledTags.ID)#" list="true">)
```

or you could also write it like this

```
WHERE 1 = 1
<cfloop query="unlabeledTags">
    AND tagID <> <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#unlabeledTags.ID#">
</cfloop>
```

Only allow the query to run when you have a recordcount on your query though.

Comment: ... and you should be using `cfqueryparam`. If you go with the `NOT IN (...)` approach, just tack on the `list=true` attribute.

Comment: If there is an empty query set, this approach will also throw an error.

Comment: @DanBracuk `Only allow the query to run when you have a recordcount on your query though.`

Comment: Thanks for all the help - will try this out + cleanup (inherited from another programmer) and will update then.

Comment: Your single line suggestion fixed it - thanks a lot to both for answer and suggestions